# Module 'Firebase' has no member named 'functions'

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-functions, cocoapods

I can't get Firebase Functions to load in xcode.

```
import Firebase
lazy var functions = Firebase.functions()
```

Installed just like the firebase docs said to.

Pod shows up under pods/pods/FirebaseFunctions.

No idea what to do here.

Firebase 6.25.0
Firebase Functions (2.5.1) (it shows up in brackets in my pod install idk why).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Firebase documentation, you should call

```
lazy var functions = Functions.functions()
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable